# Process.Start() file from Resources

Tags: c#

I want to open a Microsoft Word file(.docx). So I tried to use this code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Max\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Verenigingspakket\Verenigingspakket\Resources\Help.docx");
```

But now I want to run it like this way, by using the Help.Docx from my resources:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Properties.Resources.Help);
```

But that code doesn't work, because it is not an good overload for .Start();

Does anybody know how to work around this problem and give me a little help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the type of `Properties.Resources.Help`?

Comment: As I said in the first line of my question, it is a MS word file, so .docx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to write it to the file system first.. perhaps like this:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Help.docx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
    {
        binaryWriter.Write(Properties.Resources.Help);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I should note for those wondering: binary files within a resource are returned as byte arrays.. hence why you can pass them directly into `BinaryWriter.Write()`

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I added the help.doxc file in "Designer mode" so I just dragged it in the resources, So I think I don't need to stream it to my resources again, because I want the program to carry the help file so I don't have to give the exact location. Can't I just convert it to a binary as you did, and then immediatly use Process.Start(Properties.Resources.Help);

Comment: No. `Process.Start` won't execute a process "in-memory" based on a byte array. You have to store it on the filesystem first.. then use `Process.Start` to execute the file. If you just use a file name (omitting my C:\) then it will be written to your applications working directory. You can execute it from there using `Process.Start`.